# How to Make Graph From pcap File Information

Tags: python, python-2.7, scapy

I am trying to write a program where I use a .pcap file selected by the user, count the number of packets in the file, and extract the source IP address for each packet. After that, I would like to make a vertical bar graph, with a different bar for each IP address, and the height of each bar equivalent to the number of packets with that IP address as its source. (so if there are 3 packets from 10.2.82.5, there would be a bar labeled 10.2.82.5 that has a height of 3).

Presumably I would use a list to contain the data, but I am not sure how to increment data to find the height for each address' bar.

I am using the graphics module from [mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/), and I would like to use Scapy to extract the source IP address information.

Comment: I would advice you to use a package like [Pygal](http://pygal.org/) for creating the chart. But maybe that would require too much of you—I don’t know how familiar you are with Python.

Answer (score 0):

Use Python’s [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Feed it a list of all the IP addresses. It will return an object that can be used similarly to a dictionary (read the documentation). The keys will be the IP addresses; the values will be the numbers of occurences of these IP address.

```
>>> import collections
>>> addresses = ['127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1', '8.8.8.8', '92.12.32.3']
>>> collections.Counter(addresses)
Counter({'127.0.0.1': 2, '92.12.32.3': 1, '8.8.8.8': 1})
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion - I have implemented it and along with other pieces of code have successfully completed this task.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone curious or dealing with a similar problem, here is my final (working) code:

```js
from graphics import *
from scapy.all import *
from collections import Counter

def main():
filename = str(raw_input("What is the name of the file? "))

# sets packet source IPAs to sources, sourcenum also has # of occurrences
IP.payload_guess = []
sources = list((p[IP].src) for p in PcapReader(filename) if IP in p)
sourcenum = collections.Counter(sources)
print sourcenum

def makegraph():
    howmany = sum(1 for x in sourcenum.values())
    width = 1000/howmany

    # creates graph window with white background
    win = GraphWin("Packets Sent From Certain Addresses", 1080, 360)
    win.setBackground("white")
    Line(Point(80, 330), Point(1080, 330)).draw(win)
    Line(Point(80, 0), Point(80, 330)).draw(win)

    # creates y axis labels
    Text(Point(40, 330), " 0k pkts").draw(win)
    Text(Point(40, 280), " 3k pkts").draw(win)
    Text(Point(40, 230), " 6k pkts").draw(win)
    Text(Point(40, 180), " 9k pkts").draw(win)
    Text(Point(40, 130), " 12k pkts").draw(win)
    Text(Point(40, 80), " 15k pkts").draw(win)
    Text(Point(40, 30), " 18k+ pkts").draw(win)

    # create text and bar for each IPA
    a = 80
    subaddr = 1          
    for ipa in sourcenum:
        whooheight = sourcenum.get(str(ipa))   
        hooheight = whooheight/(18000/292)
        hoheight = 330-hooheight
        print hoheight         

        if hoheight >= 30:
            hoopyheight = hoheight
        else:
            hoopyheight = 30

        bar = Rectangle(Point(a, 330), Point(a + width, hoopyheight))
        bar.setFill("blue")
        bar.draw(win)
        Text(Point(a + width/2, 345), ipa).draw(win)
        Text(Point(a + width/2, hoopyheight-15), str(whooheight) + " packets").draw(win)
        a += width

    raw_input("Press <Enter> to quit")
    win.close()

    makegraph()

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

And I used Python 2.7 along with Scapy and the graphics module mentioned in the initial question.